# Elasticsearch error - No query registered for [query]

Tags: elasticsearch

I hope someone can help, I'm getting the following error when I try to query Elasticsearch

```
No query registered for [query]
```

The query I'm using is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "terms": {
                    "facet_1": [
                        "1",
                        "2"
                    ]
                },
                "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "fat dog food",
                            "fields": [
                                "family_name^20",
                                "parent_categories^2",
                                "description^0.2",
                                "product_suffixes^8",
                                "facet_values^10"
                            ],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "type": "best_fields",
                            "tie_breaker": 0.3
                        }
                    },
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "script_score": {
                                "script": "_score + ((_score * 0.3) + (log(1 + doc[\"popularity_score\"].value) * 2))"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "score_mode": "sum"
                }
            },
            "must_not": {
                "terms": {
                    "facet_1": [
                        "8"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "family_id",
        "family_name",
        "parent_categories",
        "description",
        "image",
        "url",
        "price_from",
        "price_to",
        "price_from_id",
        "price_to_id",
        "products_ids",
        "popularity_score"
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 48,
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc"
    }
}
```

I've tried loads of variations on this but cannot quite seem to get there. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out, to add extras to a `must`, `must_not` or `should`, they must be in an outer array like:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "facet_1": [
                            "1",
                            "2"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "fat food",
                                "fields": [
                                    "family_name^20",
                                    "parent_categories^2",
                                    "description^0.2",
                                    "product_suffixes^8",
                                    "facet_values^10"
                                ],
                                "operator": "and",
                                "type": "best_fields",
                                "tie_breaker": 0.3
                            }
                        },
                        "functions": [
                            {
                                "script_score": {
                                    "script": "_score + ((_score * 0.3) + (log(1 + doc[\"popularity_score\"].value) * 2))"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "score_mode": "sum"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "family_id",
        "family_name",
        "parent_categories",
        "description",
        "image",
        "url",
        "price_from",
        "price_to",
        "price_from_id",
        "price_to_id",
        "products_ids",
        "popularity_score"
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 48,
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc"
    }
}
```

Thanks for look anyway.